# Implicit convert CString to char*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have downloaded an sample code, so there are some CString  variables in that code which are passed to the sscanf() function as char* the compiler implicitly converts those CString and the code complie fine.the code which works fine is here:

```
CString m_strVersionXFS;
m_strVersionXFS = _T("00029903");

DWORD nVersion;
sscanf(m_strVersionXFS,"%08X",&nVersion);
```

the problem is here when i tried to write my own simple code which tries to manipulate a CString variable in the same way but the compiler says which can't convert a CString to a cahr*

Comment: just some minor correction: It is `const char*`, not `char*`. You can't make it non-const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your own code is using unicode (`UNICODE` constant defined). This means that `CString` is using wide characters, and will implicitly convert to `wchar_t*`, but not to `char*`.

If that is the case, there are three possible solutions:

1. Use `swscanf`, the wide character version of `sscanf` (recommended);
2. Explicitly use `CStringA` instead of `CString` so you're using the ANSI version of `CString`;
3. Change your project to use multi-byte characters rather than unicode (this can be done from the project properties in Visual Studio).